# Compile Nginx with module from source in Centos error

Tags: nginx, compilation

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/local/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/run/lock/subsys/nginx --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-debug

objs/ngx_modules.o \
        -lpthread -lcrypt -lpcre -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lz -lGeoIP
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/nginx-1.8.0'
make -f objs/Makefile manpage
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/nginx-1.8.0'
sed -e "s|%%PREFIX%%|/usr/local/nginx|" \
                -e "s|%%PID_PATH%%|/var/run/nginx.pid|" \
                -e "s|%%CONF_PATH%%|/etc/nginx/nginx.conf|" \
                -e "s|%%ERROR_LOG_PATH%%|/var/log/nginx/error.log|" \
                < man/nginx.8 > objs/nginx.8
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/nginx-1.8.0'
```

Why show error compiled? How fixed? Thank you. OS: Centos 6.5. ; Source Nginx compile 1.8

Here Is full log
http://pastebin.com/zVgurAig

Comment: Can you provide more output of the compile? I think the error may be further up.

Comment: Thank for your quick reply
Here is full log : http://pastebin.com/zVgurAig

Comment: This looks like a successful compile or am I missing something? I don't see error messages.

Comment: When you find the error message it is better to put it in the question :)

Comment: Type `make install` to complete. This looks like a successful compile.